# How do I filter by date in mongodb nested arrays?

Tags: mongodb, robo3t

I need a report. My data is nested. I want to filter by date range. date field string. My Mongo version 3.4.2

I want to filter the 2019 ones in cosDate.  that is, my goal is to list the 1.1.2019 - 30.12.2019 minutes. Below is the picture of my related collection

[image]
my example mongo collection https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=bcac623bb8cd401dbdb62f48bd1c3c68

Comment: Please share collection data not image

Comment: @MaheshBhatnagar ı added

Answer (score 0):

Using **aggregate** function with **filter** we can filter the data according date.

```
db.demo.aggregate(
      { "$addFields": {
        "costs": 
          {
              "$filter": {
                      "input": "$costs",
                      "as": "sn",
                      "cond": {
                        "$and": [
                          { "$gte": [ "$$sn.costDate", "01/01/2019" ] },
                           { "$lte": [ "$$sn.costDate", "12/01/2019" ] },
                     ]
              },


          }
       } 

    }}
)
```